# unexpected symbol inside primefaces graphicImage

Tags: primefaces, datatable, graphicimage

I have a graphicImage in a DataTable Colum.

My problem is that behind my icon I see a symbol like "^"

[image: unexpected symbol]

- My xhtml:

> ```
> <p:dataTable>   
> <p:column>
> <p:graphicImage 
>        value="#{pageContext.contextPath}/style/images/done.png" 
>        styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-circle" 
>        rendered="#{estudoObj.pending eq 0)}"/> 
> </p:column>
> ```

- My CSS:

> ```
> .ui-icon-circle {
>    width:20px; 
>    height:20px; 
>    border:0;
>    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-icon` has a `background-image` rule associated which you don't want in your case,
you could add :

`background-image: none !important;`

to your `ui-icon-circle` or not use `ui-icon` at all.